# Should you use "will like" or "would like" for a request/response in the present tense?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

I ran into these sentences that got me thinking about would/will:

> I will like to have your number. I would appreciate a text.

Is that grammatically incorrect or just impolite?

I suppose the above could be construed as a question. I'm also curious if the same rule holds true if you are responding to a question where you are compelled to provide a response.

For example, assume someone asks:

> For your fruit, an apple or an orange?

Why do these sound like correct responses?

> I will take an apple.
>
> I would like an apple.

At the same time, this sounds contrived?

> I will like an apple.

Is there a rule behind this, or is it just convention?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of 'Which dialects of English consider “would” to be a polite form of “will”?'.

Comment: "I will like to have your number" sounds weird, it sounds like the wrong tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely impolite to use "will" in these examples, and that is so clear, I would say it is ungrammatical (though others might not consider it to be a grammatical matter).  The problem is that the "will" sentences will be understood as requests, but using "will" assumes that the request will be granted, so it is presumptuous.  On the other hand, if you use the form with "would" which would be used in the consequent of a conditional, "If ..., then ... would ...", you convey that there are conditions under which you would not expect your request to be granted.  This makes it more polite.

Answer (score -2):

well, as you can see we use ¨WOULD¨ to be polite, meanwhile, on the other hand, we use WILL for a spontaneous decision for example:
your dad is going to put the trash in the container and you as a polite person say ¨i will do it¨.
it happens the same thing in your examples:

Why do these sound like correct responses?
**For your fruit, an apple or an orange?**

I will take an apple.

I would like an apple.